# Changing an image source to a source of a dynamic image on click

Tags: jquery, image

When my page loads I have a few small images generated from the db:

```
$.getJSON('inc/API.php',
{
    command: "get_ads_to_display"
},
function(result){
    $("#img_main").attr('src', 'images/'+result[0].ad_image_filename);
    for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++)
    {
        $("<div class='div_item_container'>"+
            "<div class='div_ad_name'>"+result[i].ad_publisher+"</div>"+
            "<div class='div_ad_image'><img src='images/"+result[i].ad_image_filename+"' /></div>"+
        "</div>").appendTo("#gallery");
    }
});
```

I also have the main image `img_main`. What I want is to change this main image's src to a source of a clicked small image (it's supposed to be some sort of a gallery). I tried this after the getJSON function:

```
$(".div_ad_image img").click(function(){
    $("#img_main").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

but it didn't work, the image src didn't change. Tried with different selectors, tried to place this code right after the `appendTo("#gallery");` part, but still had no result. So how can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) so the click event can be bind to your dynamically created images:

```
$('.div_item_container').on('click', '#div_ad_image img', function() {
    $("#img_main").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

Comment: Yup, it worked! Thank you very much! I tried the `on` event delegation too, but didn't write the code correctly so it didn't work. Now everything worked like a charm, just had to change `#div_ad_image` to `.div_ad_image` - sorry, my bad, got confused with the selector after all the changes I tried to make to the code. Thank you very much!! Will accept your answer once the system allows me to do so in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

**As you are adding image dynamically.**

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

```
$('#gallery').on('click', '.div_ad_image img', function() {
    $("#img_main").attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! Appreciate it!